# MySQL get weighted result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table with the following structure.
The Table has mostly records where gender = 1.

I'm looking for a solution to get a result set where on top around 60% of records have gender = 1 and around 40% with gender = 2 mixed, ordered by popularity desc. 
The amount of member with gender = 2 is much less, which means after the result set should only have gender = 1 records.

Member table

```
id | nickname | gender | popularity
1  | jake     | 1      | 80
2  | mike     | 1      | 88
3  | dave     | 1      | 75
4  | jenny    | 2      | 85
5  | peter    | 1      | 83
6  | nina     | 2      | 88
7  | mister   | 1      | 77
8  | drake    | 1      | 80
```

Result should be something like, it must not meet exactly weighted list. the goal is to see mixed results of both genders.

```
id | nickname | gender | popularity
2  | mike     | 1      | 88
5  | peter    | 1      | 83
6  | nina     | 2      | 88
1  | jake     | 1      | 80
8  | drake    | 1      | 80
4  | jenny    | 2      | 85
7  | mister   | 1      | 77
3  | dave     | 1      | 75
```

My so far best result was (it don't take care about the 40:60 split):

```
SET @rank=0;
SET @rank2=0;
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, q.* FROM (SELECT * FROM test WHERE gender = 1     ORDER BY popularity DESC) AS q
UNION
SELECT @rank2:=@rank2+1 AS rank, q.*  FROM (SELECT * FROM test WHERE gender = 2 ORDER BY popularity DESC) AS q
) AS r ORDER BY rank;
```

Comment: This is a requirements specification, not a question. Pls ask a question and also share what you have tried.

Comment: To clarify, you are asking for us to produce a list where at most 40% of entries are `gender = 2` and the rest are `gender = 1`?  Or are you asking for us to produce a list sorted solely on popularity where you expect none of the `gender = 2` entries will be returned, though it may be theoretically possible?

Comment: @toonice yes I'm asking for a list that shows 40% of entries where gender = 2 and the rest is gender = 1

Comment: Should the records be mixed together or should it be all of `gender = 1` followed by all of `gender = 2`?

Comment: @toonice it should be mixed and sort by popularity desc, I have updated my question with my so far best solution

Answer (score 0):

Please try...

```
SET @gender1Count = SELECT COUNT( * )
                    FROM tblMember
                    WHERE gender = 1;

SET @gender2Count = SELECT COUNT( * )
                    FROM tblMember
                    WHERE gender = 2;

SET @totalCount = SELECT COUNT( * )
                  FROM tblMember;

SELECT id AS id,
       nickname AS nickname,
       gender AS gender,
       popularity AS popularity
FROM tblMember
JOIN ( SELECT id AS id
       FROM tblMember
       WHERE gender = 1
       ORDER BY popularity DESC
       LIMIT CASE
             WHEN @gender1Count > @totalCount * 3 / 5 
                 ROUND( @gender2Count * 3 / 2 )
             ELSE
                 @gender1Count
             END
       UNION
       SELECT id AS id
       FROM tblMember
       WHERE gender = 2
       ORDER BY popularity DESC
       LIMIT CASE
             WHEN @gender1Count > @totalCount * 3 / 5 
                 @gender2Count
             ELSE
                 ROUND( @gender1Count * 2 / 3 )
             END
     ) nominees ON tblMember.id = nominees.id
ORDER BY popularity DESC;
```

The above will give you a list where 60% of entries are `gender = 1` and 40% are `gender = 2`.  Please note that this is not the same as 60% or more of the total list as `gender = 1` with the balance `gender = 2` (or 40% or more of the total list as `gender = 2` and the balance `gender = 1`).

It does this by forming a list of those whose `gender` equals `1` and sorting it into descending order of `popularity`.  It then determines how many of the top entries it will grab from this list using `LIMIT` by checking if the count of `gender = 1` members exceeds 60% (3/5ths) of the list.  If it does then we will need to reduce the number of `gender = 1` records to be retrieved to 3/2 times the count of `gender = 2` members.  The `id`'s of the chosen records are then returned.

(A quickish explanation for those who aren't great at fractions, 40% is the same as 2/5 (two fifths).  If `gender = 2` has two fifths of the final list then `gender = 1` must have the other three fifths (3/5).  To find the size of 3/5ths of the list we start with the known 2/5ths (the count of `gender = 2`) and divide that into 2 so that we know the size of 1/5th of the list.  We can then multiply this 1/5 by 3 to determine how many record will make up 3/5ths (60%) of our list.)

Similar logic is used to form the list of `gender = 2` members to be included in the final list.

(Please note that the records at the end of each list will likely have popularity values equal to those of the most popular excluded members whose gender corresponds to each list.  In the absence of any subsorting in the formation of the two lists the selection of those that are or are not chosen will be arbitrary (and essentially semirandom).)

The two lists are then joined using the `UNION` operator in what is a simple type of *vertical* join.  (Note : The more familiar `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, etc., are all types of *horizontal* joins).

An inner `JOIN` is then performed upon our list of amalgamated `id`'s with our original table, giving us our 60% / 40% list.  Finally, this list is sorted into descending order of `popularity`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: thank you, after fixed the first error, must use brackets in SET  (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM test WHERE gender = 1) I'm still search what causes a syntax error regardind LIMIT and CASE, I already add THEN but still not working.